# JButtons not placing according to me inside a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I've been working on a Java project where I created a `JPanel` and added a background image to it. I have to add a `JButton` to it and when I add that `JButton` to the `JPanel`, it just places it in the center and not according to the bounds that I have set. Here is the code:

```java
ImageIcon rltbg = new ImageIcon("src/main/resources/img/result.png");
JPanel rslt = new JPanel() {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics gk) {
        super.paintComponent(gk);
        gk.drawImage(rltbg.getImage(), 0, 0, null);
    }
};
rslt.setBounds(50, 400, 700, 250);

JLabel tvote1 = new JLabel("here -> "+rc1);
tvote1.setBounds(100, 455, 150,50);
rslt.add(tvote1);
```

It is adding it to the upper center of `JPanel`.
I have tried changing the bounds but it also didn't work.

A screenshot of it:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I have added a screenshot of it. and It also doesn't work when I set the layout to null.

Comment: Are the yellow rectangles (in the image that you posted) `JButton`s? And is that a `JLabel` above the yellow rectangles?

Comment: no, the yellow rectangles are not Jbutton or any other components. they are in the picture that I used to set the background of jpannel. And the text "candidate no. 1 ->" above the yellow rectangle is JLabel of which we are talking.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2Ftutorial%2Fuiswing%2F%2F/layout/border.html) for [`JPanel`] `rslt`. Then create another `JPanel` to contain [`JLabel`] `tvote1`. Default layout manager for `JPanel` is [FlowLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2Ftutorial%2Fuiswing%2F%2F/layout/flow.html) and default alignment for `FlowLayout` is center. Then add that `JPanel` to the top part of the `BorderLayout`. Then the `JLabel` will appear centered at the top of `rslt`. Below code demonstrates.

```java
ImageIcon rltbg = new ImageIcon("src/main/resources/img/result.png");
JPanel rslt = new JPanel() {
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics gk) {
        super.paintComponent(gk);
        gk.drawImage(rltbg.getImage(), 0, 0, null);
    }
};
rslt.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());
JLabel tvote1 = new JLabel("here -> "+rc1);
JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
topPanel.add(tvote1);
rslt.add(topPanel, java.awt.BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
```

#### EDIT

Here is a complete example. Note that I used a different image to yours as I don't have yours.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class BkGrdImg implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        createAnddisplayGui();
    }

    private void createAnddisplayGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel rslt = new JPanel() {
            private int w;
            private Image img;

            {
                JLabel label = new JLabel("String");
                Font f = label.getFont();
                FontMetrics fm = label.getFontMetrics(f);
                w = fm.stringWidth("String");
                try {
                    img = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\USER\\Pictures\\284kd.png"));
                }
                catch (IOException xIo) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(xIo);
                }
            }

            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));
            }

            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
            }
        };
        rslt.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setOpaque(false);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("JLabel");
        topPanel.add(label);
        rslt.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.add(rslt);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new BkGrdImg());
    }
}
```

Here is a screen capture:

[image: screen capture]

Note that `JPanel` is opaque by default. Hence `topPanel.setOpaque(false)` will ensure that the background image (of `rslt`) will be displayed. Also, overriding method `getPreferredSize()` will ensure that the preferred size of `rslt` will be the size of its background image.

Comment: I don't want it to appear centered at the top. I want it to appear in the rslt panel and above the rectangles of the background image.

Answer (score -1):

you must the setBounds better writing ,

```
rslt.setBounds(50, 400,700,250)
tvote1.setBounds(100, 455, 150,50)
```

because setBound(Measure from left,Measure from top, width, height)
and make the `JPnal.setLayout(null);`

Comment: It doesn't matter how you call `setBounds` if you don't first set the layout manager of the `JPanel` to null.

Comment: Calling `setBounds(...)` and using a null layout in this situation is very wrong. -1. The OP is asking an XY Problem type question because they don't know enough to know that doing this will lead to rigid, hard to enhance and debug GUI's, GUI's that look bad on most other platforms. Our job as answerers is not to encourage them to follow this erroneous path. If you don't know enough about the Swing library and how to best use it, then best to avoid posting misleading answers.